# Maxima. How to prevent degree calculations

Tags: numbers, calculation, maxima, simplification

Is it possible for all calculations in the expression for numbers in a power to be prevented? Perhaps by pre-processing the expression or adding tellsimp rules? Or some other way?

For example, to

```
distrib (10 ^ 10 * (x + 1));
```

which produces:

```
1000000000 x + 1000000000
```

instead issued:

```
10 ^ 10 * x + 10 ^ 10
```

And similarly

```
factor (10 ^ 10 * x + 10 ^ 10);
```

returned:

```
10 ^ 10 * (x + 1);
```

Just as

```
factor(200);
2^3*5^2
```

represents power of numbers, only permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, although I don't see a good solution. Here's something I tried as an experiment, which is to display integers in factored form. I am working with Maxima 5.44.0 + SBCL.

```
(%i1) :lisp (defun integer-formatter (x) ($factor x))
INTEGER-FORMATTER
(%i1) :lisp (setf (get 'integer 'formatter) 'integer-formatter)
INTEGER-FORMATTER
(%i1) (x + 1000)^3;
                                       3  3 3
(%o1)                            (x + 2  5 )
(%i2) 10^10*(x + 1);
                                2 5  2 5
(%o2)                         (2    5   ) (x + 1)
```

This is only a modification of the display; the internal representation is just a single integer.

```
(%i3) :lisp $%
((MTIMES SIMP) 10000000000 ((MPLUS SIMP) 1 $X))
```

That seems kind of clumsy, since e.g. `2^(2*5)*5^(2*5)` isn't really more comprehensible than `10000000000`.

A separate question is whether the arithmetic on `10^10` could be suppressed, so it actually stays as `10^10` and isn't represented internally as `10000000000`. I'm pretty sure that would be difficult. Unfortunately Maxima is not too good with retracting identities which are applied, particularly with the built-in identities which are applied to perform arithmetic and other operations.